# extracting data from json in python as float

Tags: python, json

I want to extract the longitude and latitude from http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json/.
I use requests to save the page but can someone help extract only the numbers?

Comment: Please post example data and any attempts you have made

Answer (score 3):

A response object in `requests` has a `json` method.  So you need only do:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json/")

coords = response.json()["iss_position"]

lon = float(coords["longitude"])
lat = float(coords["latitude"])

print(lon, lat)
```

which gives (for example):

```
164.2242 27.9186
```

*(Note: if the response is not in the expected format then there are various places where this could raise an exception.  You could put in various checks, for example check that `response.status_code == 200` before calling `response.json()`, but it may be just as easy to catch the exceptions if required.)*

Answer (score 0):

load the string of the page into dictionary using `json`:

```
import json
import requests

page = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json/'

with requests.get(page) as pg:
    data = json.loads(pg.text)

#actually could just do data = pg.json()
```

output:

```
{u'timestamp': 1593559635, u'message': u'success', u'iss_position': {u'latitude': u'26.5951', u'longitude': u'165.5561'}}

lon = float(data['iss_position']['longitude'])
lat = float(data['iss_position']['latitude'])
```

Comment: see the comment saying exactly that, btw it's a method

Comment: You're right, I had `.text` in my mind when I said attribute.